# When should we use redeploy button in Azure Resource groups

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

Azure resource groups give a redeploy button not sure how and when to use that. Would appreciate best practices.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when we facing difficulties troubleshooting, redeploying the deployment may help.

For example, when we can't connect to Azure VM or application access to windows-based Azure VM, we can try to redeploy it. When you redeploy a VM, it **moves** the VM to a new node within the Azure infrastructure and then powers it back on, **retaining all your configuration options and associated resources.**

More information about redeploy Azure VM, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/redeploy-to-new-node).

By default, when we select `redeploy` in Azure resource group deployments, Azure will use this template to deploy this resource.

Comment: so reploy is not meant to be used in a continuous deplotment pipeline. But when something is not working it overrides it and uses the old config.

Comment: Yes, you are right. when something is not working, redeploy will overrides it with the old config.